# Is there an El Capitan Update only?

Tags: macos, software-update

The title is a bit confusing so I will explain below:

The El Capitan downloaded from the Apple Mac Store is *big* enough to do a fresh installation as well as an upgrade to your current OS version.

The size of this however is very large.

## My Question

Is it possible to download just the update from OS X 10.10.5. For example to update from 10.10.4 to 10.10.5 there is an updater which is smaller than the combo update. Is there one for an update to 10.11.0/1.

*Hope this makes sense*

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will still receive updates for Yosemite via App Store updates if you don't upgrade to 10.11.

Comment: @Arc676  Yeah but I prefer to download then off Apple Website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. El Capitan is a major release which replaces *a lot of* (or even most) files of the OS. So the "big" Installer from the Store is both an Installer and an Updater.

Comment: Sulk...I guess I just have to download the huge download time

Comment: If you have a laptop, you can always go to the next Apple Retail Store and download it through the WiFi there.